# Integrating Nemerle in Visual C# 2010 Express

Tags: visual-studio, nemerle

I would like to use Nemerle to write parts of a .NET application. Is there a plugin for Visual C# 2010 Express?
The only one I found returns an error because it is thought for a different version of Visual C#.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The plan is to release Nemerle 1.0 with full 2008 integration ASAP, then work on 2010. There are major differences between these versions of Visual Studio.

Comment: hey don reba you are alive :)

Comment: @Don Reba: any news on Nemerle Visual Studio support?

Answer (score 2):

There is no full working add on for VS2010 right now.
There is some early stage work.

[image: VS2010 early integration]

If you wish, you can help with this project.

Comment: The VS2010 addon is almost stable. You can try it ! But doesn't work with Express.

Comment: Nemerle with integration in VS Gallery: http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d93dc0a-0ce9-4b97-970c-ab1993eb934a